# Add a class under a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add a class name 'disabled' under a parent div call 'anchorxx'

[image]

The disabled class div can be anywhere in the anchorXX divs

is it possible to do it with jquery ? i have no idea how i can manage to do it.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: test case? a simple approach is `$(".anchor"+ id + " > div").addClass("disabled")`. class will be added to the immediate div child element of `.anchor1` div

Comment: Thanks eltonkami, your answer is very constructive

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple approach is

```
$(".anchor"+ id + " > div").addClass("disabled")
```

class will be added to the immediate div child element of .anchor1 div

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery prefix selector and `find` the relevant element. Use `addClass` to add the required class

```
$('div[id^=anchor]').find('.whereYouwantToadd').addClass('someClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's wildcard selector for this purpose.

[link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

you can find the anchor id and change the class of underlying `div` like this:

```
$('div[id*="anchor"]').child('div.fiche-left-disabled').addClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the 'disabled' class to its first children:

```
$('#anchor1').children().first().addClass('disabled')
```

For all anchors

```
$('div[id^="anchor"]').children().first().addClass('disabled')
```